# Books for learning Cryptocurrency

Tags: cryptography, blockchain

Please suggest a good for mathematical section of studying cryptocurrency.

Comment: My advice: Don't bother.  It's a [Merkle tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) with [Proof of work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_work) as consensus.  The rest is standard computer science.

Comment: thanks..appreciate it